# Why was Madagascar settled by far-flung Austronesian seafarers?

Tags: ancient-india, migration, madagascar, austronesian

I have found that seafarers from Oceania were the first to inhabit Madagascar instead of the much closer Africans in what is today Mozambique. Why is this so?

[image: Polynesian Migrations]

Comment: Probably worth looking that the prevailing winds and currents in the Indian Ocean. I suspect these make it easier to sail from east to west.

Answer (score 7):

Polynesian navigators made good use of ocean winds and currents. When following the [Indian Ocean Gyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_Gyre), the most logical way to arrive to Madagascar is from the East:

[image: Indian Ocean Gyre]

If you look up the [South Pacific Gyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Pacific_Gyre#/media/File:South_Pacific_Gyre.png), you'll notice a similar pathway to New Zealand from the Polynesian triangle. Also, on the topic of the question mark to the right side of your map, [the Incan had (Polynesian) chicken](http://www.birds.cornell.edu/Page.aspx%3Fsrcid%3D977%26pid%3D275) before Europeans arrived.

Comment: I'm *so* happy for you that you got the opportunity to write a good on-topic answer centered around your South Pacific Gyre. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D.: hehe, I kind of felt the same way when I saw the question. ;-) ([Context](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51809/why-were-madagascar-and-new-zealand-discovered-so-late) for future readers who might wonder what that comment was about.)

Comment: Related: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/30324/why-were-la-r%c3%a9union-and-mauritius-uninhabited/34988#34988

Answer (score 1):

(Instead of commenting, which can get lengthy, especially with questions, I thought it best to deliver this in the format of an answer.)

**Issue:** The answer does not fit the question. Given that OP has *accepted* the answer, makes me hesitant whether to edit the question or comment on the accepted answer.

**Explanation:** If the question was "***How*** did Austronesians arrive in Madagascar?", the accepted answer *might* fit the bill. On the other hand, if OP really is asking "why" (i.e. an ultimate cause), I think more context is required.

In fact, even the *how* aspect leaves out agency of Austronesians, as if **oceanic navigation skills** at such an early period was normal. They were not. This very recent [**2017 Oxford Research Encyclopedia**](http://oxfordre.com/asianhistory/view/10.1093/acrefore/9780190277727.001.0001/acrefore-9780190277727-e-30) entry explains the feat, i.e. shipbuilding and navigation skills.

Just in case anyone is really looking for the *why* and not the *how* of the migration of Southeast Borneo culture to Madagascar, the short answer is trade during 1st millennium CE between Insular Southeast Asia and Indian sub-continent and eastern Africa, namely, **[Indian Ocean trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_trade)**.

According to most recent genomic data, this was during early 10th century, at the height of [Srivijayan influence as a trading empire](https://www.khanacademy.org/humanities/world-history/medieval-times/cultural-interactions-along-trade-routes/a/the-srivijaya-empire-trade-and-culture-in-the-indian-ocean).

On genomic data and analysis: *[Malagasy Genetic Ancestry Comes from an Historical Malay Trading Post in Southeast Borneo](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/33/9/2396/2579411#aHR0cHM6Ly9hY2FkZW1pYy5vdXAuY29tL21iZS9hcnRpY2xlLXBkZi8zMy85LzIzOTYvMTc0NzQyNzcvbXN3MTE3LnBkZkBAQDA=)* (2016).